# Insert a list to row in pandas?

Tags: pandas

The data may look like this

```
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0              
1  1  5  6
2  2  7  4
```

```
list=[1.2,1.3,1.4]
```

How may I insert to it to a dataframe?

```
   0    1    2
0  1.1  1.2  1.3              
1  1    5    6
2  2    7    4
```

I only use a loop to do it.

Is there any function do it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? just add 1 row to a dataframe? Or do you want to do this frequently?

Comment: just for one time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.loc` to select the first row, then insert your list:

```
mylist = [1.2,1.3,1.4]
df.loc[0] = mylist
```

**Output**

```
     0    1    2
0  1.2  1.3  1.4
1  1.0  5.0  6.0
2  2.0  7.0  4.0
```